# Can not browse subpages/typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want a little menu to browse my pages and subpages in TYPO3 7.6
My page tree looks like this:
[page tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEviD.png)

and my code to do so :

```
page.2 = HMENU
page.2.special = browse
page.2.special{
items = prev| next
items.prevnextToSection = 1

}
page.2.1 = TMENU
page.2.1.NO.linkWrap = |&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;|*||*||
```

My Problem is that typo skips the subpages and only browse the sites "1,2,3".
`.prevnextToSection` should deal with this, but i don´t understand why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`prev` and `next` only work on the same level. You want to use `prevsection` and `prevsection_last`.

```
page.2.special.items = prev|prevsection_last|prevsection|next
```

You might want top read up on the documentation, but the whole topic is a big confusing, because it works on levels of the page tree.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#special-browse

Comment: Note: Untestet.

Comment: I´ve used prevsection and nextsection but they aren´t displayed. only next and prev are available and clickable.

Comment: is prevsection/nextsection removed ?